How to fetch defined/updated variables' id and their values from a string of code in python?
I am working on a project wherein I want to parse each line of code (present in the form of a string) in python one by one. I want the declared/updated identifiers' id and their assigned values.
Consider a string of code here:
a = 1
a, b = 2, 0
lst = [2, 3, b]
lst[1] = 9

And I am expecting something like this after parsing each line:
{a:1}
{a:2, b:0}
{lst:[2, 3, 0]}
{(lst, 1):9}

I tried parsing the given code string using python's ast module. I got an abstract syntax tree as a result. Since I want the variables and their values I thought I needed the ast.Name and ast.Constant nodes. So, I tried iterating over the nodes in ast.walk and checking if they are an instance of these (ast.Name and ast.Constant) classes. But given the complex nature of code, how do I know exactly what value is assigned to what? Also, how do I deal with code-string that has loops?

ast.walk won't help you, because when it yields an AST node, you have no idea where in the AST it is, but you definitely want to do different things with a node depending on, e.g. whether it's on the left or right of the =.
You'll probably need to write a (recursive) function to 'evaluate' an AST node, where the action to perform depends on the type of the node. For example, an Assign node has two children, targets and value. You'll want to evaluate the value (which might return an integer, or a tuple, or a list), and then do something appropriate with that, depending on what's in targets.
As for loops, you didn't give an example of what the program should produce when the code-string has loops.

I was thinking if there was an API that could do this, like some chatgpt's API?

And, talking about loops, I am myself not clear how I want the result. I just wanted to tell you that I am not working on assignment statements alone.

If you're hoping for an API that can do this, I suspect the closest thing you'll find is Python's exec function. For instance:
lines = [
    "a = 1",
    "a, b = 2, 0",
    "lst = [2, 3, b]",
    "lst[1] = 9",
]

my_locals = {}

for line in lines:
    exec(line, None, my_locals)
    print(my_locals)

prints:
{'a': 1}
{'a': 2, 'b': 0}
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'lst': [2, 3, 0]}
{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'lst': [2, 9, 0]}

which isn't exactly what you asked for, but might be what you want.

This is a way, with one problem that I have to execute all the lines which have been executed so far again while executing each line. Also, I may run into some dangerous code.

Indeed, if you accept input from untrusted sources, this technique could do undesirable things. I think there are ways to mitigate this, but it wasn't part of your original question.
